# Beautiful Soup and Splinter - get href and src attributes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, splinter

This is the code:

```
url = f'https://www.premierleague.com/players'

# Initiate a splinter instance of the URL
browser.visit(url)

browser.find_by_tag('div[class="table playerIndex"]')
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.html, 'html.parser')
for el in soup:
    td =  el.findAll('td')
    for each_td in td:
        url = each_td.find('a', href=True)
        print (url)
```

which hits targeted items, but followed by `None`:

```
<a class="playerName" href="/players/19970/Max-Aarons/overview"><img alt="" class="img" data-player="p232980" data-script="pl_player-image" data-size="40x40" data-widget="player-image" src="//platform-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/premierleague/photos/players/40x40/Photo-Missing.png"/>Max Aarons</a>
None
None
<a class="playerName" href="/players/13279/Abdul-Rahman-Baba/overview"><img alt="" class="img" data-player="p118335" data-script="pl_player-image" data-size="40x40" data-widget="player-image" src="//platform-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/premierleague/photos/players/40x40/Photo-Missing.png"/>Abdul Rahman Baba</a>
None
None
```

---

How do I get `href` and `src` values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access an element's attributes and properties as a dictionary.

```
for el in soup: 
    td = el.findAll('td') 
    for each_td in td: 
        link = each_td.find('a', href=True)
        if link:
            print(link['href'])
        image = each_td.find('img')
        if image:
            print(image['src'])
```

Comment: I had tried that, as a dict. the catch was the `if` condition, getting rid of `None`. thank you

Comment: also, it is important to keep the argument `href=True`, otherwise `src` delivered is `//platform-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/premierleague/photos/players/40x40/Photo-Missing.png`, instead of actual resource `https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/40x40/p232980.png`

Comment: Happy to help. I've re-added the `href=True` parameter.